# Swift - base64EncodingStringWithOptions not working Xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

```
let username = "operator"
let password = "pass"
let loginString = NSString(format: "%@:%@", username, password)
let loginData: NSData = loginString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.fromMask(0))

// create the request
let url = NSURL(string: "myurl")
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
request.setValue("Basic \(base64LoginString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```

The above code was working fine pre-Xcode 6.1 but now I get an error on the `base64LoginString` constant.

```
/Users/Joel/Project/MapViewController.swift:31:74: 'NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Type' does not have a member named 'fromMask'
```

I am relatively new to Swift and would like to also ask some advice as to how I should go about solving this sort of issue without having to post to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fromMask()` constructor does not exist anymore in the current version of Swift.
To specify "no option", use

```
let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(0))
```

or simply

```
let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(nil)
```

For **Swift 2** (compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/32499968/1187415):

```
let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])
```

For **Swift 3:**

```
let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedString()
```

Comment: Note that using `nil` will generate an "Incompatible pointer to integer conversion..." warning

Comment: @mokagio: `loginData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(nil)` compiles without any warnings in my Xcode 6.1.1.