# Swift 2 base64 Encoding Yield Different Results

Tags: ios, swift2

Swift 1.2

```
let apiLoginString = NSString(format: "%@:%@", API_USERNAME, API_PASSWORD);
let apiLoginData: NSData = apiLoginString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!;
var base64ApiLoginString = apiLoginData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(nil);
```

Swift 2

```
let apiLoginString = NSString(format: "%@:%@", API_USERNAME, API_PASSWORD);
let apiLoginData: NSData = apiLoginString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!;
var base64ApiLoginString = apiLoginData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions());
```

Those 2 approach yield different results. In Swift 2 we cannot pass in `nil` anymore;

```
apiLoginData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(nil);
```

I have also tried passed in `NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength` in Swift 2. But the results is still differemt

Any thoughts?

**UPDATE 2: It is not the problem with Swift 1.2 or Swift 2. Oddly enough those 2 prints out different results..  What the F!!**

**UPDATE 3: Turns out that as Martin pointed out, I have some invisible character in my API_USERNAME variable**

```
class RequestHelper: NSObject {
static var API_USERNAME: NSString = "⁠⁠⁠abc";
static var API_PASSWORD: NSString = "123";
static var USERNAME: NSString = "abc"
static var PASSWORD: NSString = "123"


class func signUpUser() {
    //Base64
    var loginString = NSString(format: "%@:%@", USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    var loginData: NSData = loginString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!;
    var base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([]);

    print("BASE 64 \(base64LoginString)");//RESULT YWJjOjEyMw==

    let apiLoginString = NSString(format: "%@:%@", API_USERNAME, API_PASSWORD);
    let apiLoginData: NSData = apiLoginString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!;
    var base64ApiLoginString = apiLoginData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([]);

    print("BASE 64 \(base64ApiLoginString)");// RESULT IS 4oGg4oGg4oGgYWJjOjEyMw==
}
```

Comment: extra part in second encoded string (4oGg4oGg4oGg) is literally nil when decoded. don't know why Foundation add such useless head

Comment: I recommend you use native String type and string interpolation instead of NSString formatter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Similarly as in [Swift 2.0 calendar components error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30769387/swift-2-0-calendar-components-error) or [Swift 2.0 - Binary Operator "|" cannot be applied to two UIUserNotificationType operands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30761996/swift-2-0-binary-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-two-uiusernotificationtype),
`NSDataBase64EncodingOptions` is an `OptionSetType` in Swift 2.
It offers a set-like interface and can be initialized from an array
literal.

So valid options would be for example:

```
base64EncodedStringWithOptions([]) // no options
base64EncodedStringWithOptions([.Encoding64CharacterLineLength])
base64EncodedStringWithOptions([.Encoding64CharacterLineLength, .EncodingEndLineWithCarriageReturn])
```

---

Full example:

```
let apiLoginString = NSString(format: "%@:%@", "user", "password")
let apiLoginData = apiLoginString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
let base64ApiLoginString = apiLoginData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])

print(base64ApiLoginString)
// dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==
```

Comment: Yes, but oddly enough, the result of the encoded string is totally different. Any thoughts?

Comment: @JayVDiyk: I cannot reproduce that. I have added a full (Swift 2) example to the answer, and I get exactly the same output for Swift 1.2.

Comment: please check my updated question, this is weird. or am i missing something?

Comment: I have officially lost my mind. Please try that out if it behaves the same on your place.

Comment: @JayVDiyk: Your API_USERNAME has some invisible characters right at the start, before the letter "a". If you remove those (or rewrite the string) you get identical results!